# Stack Overflow Survey Result - SharePoint

Tags: discussion

Based on the [Stack Overflow Survey Result](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2018-promotion#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms),

> The Sharepoint is the most dreaded development platform for the **second**
>   year in a row!!!

[image]

- What about your opinion?
- What do you think about the future of SharePoint?

Comment: `What about your opinion?`: **Ouch.**

Comment: 2 years back-to-back. Looks like too many people hate it :) . Not sure why, may be too many changes too little time to get used to it. Future of SP - well SP is not SP anymore, its becoming more and more client-side stuff with SPFx becoming more popular over time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My opinion is it's not flexible enough, with too many restrictions. Developers like control and when something isn't in their full control, they can't stand it.

SharePoint best practices states we aren't supposed to touch the database, we have to do CRUD operations through the SharePoint API (PowerShell, CSOM, SSOM, REST, etc) without direct connection with the database, and the documentation on it isn't the most in depth -- many blogs make up for the lack of documentation.

Also, it's a huge platform, with many many moving parts and so much you can do wrong, so many "gotchas", and plenty more workarounds to things that haven't been fixed in 2 versions. Not to mention SharePoint Online is even MORE restrictive.

In short, SharePoint is big and restrictive and developers can't muster up the patience for it.

Comment: what are your thoughts about the future of SP ?

Comment: SharePoint Online is and can be sexy -- but the difficulty of modification and branding of the modern pages is disappointing.

Comment: Coming from Dynamics background - Not only SP, MS is changing/restricting the cloud/online interactions only through Web Api/services, no access to DB, PowerShell commands, client side/server side plugins, Connectors to use with Flow, PowerApps, LogicApps, etc becomes Developers day-to-day lifestyle.. so we will accustom to that..

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is no more SharePoint. It is more online and more on cloud. Like integrating into azure. Developers are getting frustrated due to changes in technologies over short period of time in SharePoint Online and Clients are yet to accept new versions of SharePoint in which there is less customization and Microsoft is focusing on more and more cloud side customization in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the responses already posted contain likely issues for developers who completed the survey. And there is probably more.
Could it represent a bias of StackOverflow against enterprise and mature platforms? If you look at the most dreaded databases, they are IBM DB2 and Oracle. Those are two of the most mature databases with the most application to large, enterprise data.